# Is there any way to enable 2 HttpSessionStrategy together in Spring Session?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-session

I am using Spring Session to do the session management. Meanwhile, we have some REST API in our application and we want to use token-based auth as well.

So, we want to enable 2 HttpSessionStrategy together, `CookieHttpSessionStrategy` and `HeaderHttpSessionStrategy`. In that way, our application can auth be cookies and token at the same time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd have to implement your own `HttpSessionStrategy` (note that in Spring Session 2.0 this API has been replaced with `HttpSessionIdResolver`) that knows how to handle both cookie and header. You should be able to use composition for that and therefore reuse existing `HttpSessionStrategy` implementations provided by Spring Session by delegating to them.

Of course, this comes with some complexity, as you'd have to consider which mechanism takes precedence.